# How to change my base URL

Tags: uri

I have built a website using drupal. Now, the base URL is http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/drupal.
But I want to change base URL as http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
How do I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have access to add vhost in apache? If yes then one clean way is to add a virtualhost to map the directory where you have installed Drupal (including the drupal folder) to ServerName which is xx.xx.xx.xx and reload apache..

Comment: Hi Dipen,
How to add a virtualhost to map the directory where you have installed Drupal? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

go to `yousite/sites/default` and open the `settings.php` file and find `$base_url` and change it to the new value (somewhere around line 270).

**NOTE :** `settings.php` is a read-only file, you need to clear the read-only flag first to make the changes. You'll need to restart the server to update the changes.

Comment: I suppose there may be exotic configurations where it may be necessary, but in most cases you shouldn't have to restart the server at all - the change will go into effect immediately.

Comment: when I change the base_url to my domain name. I get much error on page. for example, "failed to load resoutce". because the resource location has been changed to "http://domainname/xxxx/xxx.css" (original is http://ip/xxxx/xxx.css)
why ??

Comment: You need to check where the base installation of your Drupal site is. If it is at the root of the server (e.g. www), then you need to give `$base_url=siteroot`; else if it is in some folder inside the root of the server, then you need to have `site_root/path_to_drupal_install_folder` value for your `$base_url`

Comment: Its not woking for me.

Answer (score 5):

There is a global variable called `$base_url` that you can set in sites/default/settings.php. Try changing its value.