# Transferred website not referencing images files correctly

Tags: acquia-dev-desktop

I recently copied some Drupal websites from a local Acquia Dev Desktop web server to a local MAMP web server.

Curiously the sites work except the graphics are not loading. i.e., stylesheets load, database connects but no images.

The browser’s error console shows that the root dir folder is not being read. For example:

http://localhost:8888/sites/all/themes/mytheme/images/some_image.png

should instead be referenced as such..

http://localhost:8888/mysitename/sites/all/themes/mytheme/images/some_image.png

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix?

Comment: Have you set your base_url? see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33389/how-to-change-my-base-url for details

Comment: yes, good point. since using Drupal i haven't once had to set the base url either locally (laptop) or once launched. but that is clearly the problem. there is a commented out variable for this in the setting.php file which i have now set. but it's still not working.

Comment: Are only theme images not shown or also other uploaded images in content? Perhaps do a search on the database on the old (wrong) paths and see where they are set?